# Add values to dataframe column after certain index

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
No     Data    Sentence
32      xxx      yyyy
45      hhh      uuuu
 .       .        . 
 .       .        . 
8726    aaa      bbbb
```

Where the `No` column is unordered, now I have `x` which is list of sentences and I want to add that list to the `Sentence` column after my last index. So my new dataframe will look like:

```
No     Data    Sentence
32      xxx      yyyy
45      hhh      uuuu
    .       .         . 
    .       .         . 
8726    aaa      bbbb
NaN     NaN      x[0]
NaN     NaN      x[1]
 .       .         .
 .       .         .
NaN     NaN      x[n]
```

I know we can directly assign list to column by assign function but it'll assign list value from beginning and I don't even know size of my list. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the list of sentences to a dataframe and then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence': x})
pd.concat([df,x], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very muchh for help

Comment: @VIBHUBAROT: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

First turn your list into a dataframe:

```
listDF = pd.DataFrame(list, columns='Sentence')
```

Then use [pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append)

```
extended_df = df.appned(listDF)
```

To test:

create df1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
```

print it:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

create df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([5, 6], columns=list('B'))
```

print it:

```
   B
0  5
1  6
```

finally:

```
df.append(df2)
```

results:

```
     A  B
0  1.0  2
1  3.0  4
0  NaN  5
1  NaN  6
```